# Vue: how to access user info from local storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm building a project in Vue js and i have used Vue sessions to save user's info after being logged in,i'm trying to access user info (role) as shown below but it gives me all his info when i typed
console.log(sessionStorage.user); i've also tried console.log(sessionStorage.user.role); but it didn't work , any help please on how to access only role? and thanks in advance

Login Page

```html
  await axios
          .post("api/user/login", this.login)

          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            let newToken = response.data.response.token;
            window.token = newToken;
            let user = response.data.response.user; //response
            sessionStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
            sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

Logged in area

```html
console.log(sessionStorage);
console.log(sessionStorage.user)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionstore.user).role)
```

You stored your data with `JSON.stringify` so you have to parse your data!

Comment: No, it's not possible, but you can manage that by adding a variable in `data()` and edit it with some methods...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for reading the sessionStorage item is as follows:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)